# Prove sequence is not convergent in a complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm looking over some previous analysis exams and I've come across this question:

> Consider the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers and the metric function
>   defined as:
>
> $$d(x, y) = \begin{cases} 1 ~ \text{if} ~ x \ne y \\ 0 ~ \text{if} ~ x
> = y \end{cases}$$
>
> 1. Is the sequence $(x_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ defined by $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ convergent in this metric space?
> 2. Is this metric space complete?

---

**For part 1:**

Assume that $(x_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ is convergent to a real $a$. Then, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$d(x_n, a) < \epsilon ~ ~ \text{for all} ~ ~ n \geq N$$

Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Then $d(x_n, a) < \frac{1}{2} ~ ~ \implies ~ ~ x_n = a ~ ~ \implies ~ ~ a = \frac{1}{n} ~ ~ \text{for all} ~ ~ n \geq N$. This is a contradiction, so $(x_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ does not converge in this metric space.

**For part 2:**

A metric space is complete iff every Cauchy sequence is convergent. A Cauchy sequence is a sequence $(x_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$d(x_n, x_m) < \epsilon ~ ~ \text{for all} ~ ~ n, m \geq N$$

Reusing part 1's approach, we let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Then if $(x_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, it must follow that $x_n = x_m$ for all $n, m \geq N$. So the sequence is constant for $n \geq N$, and as such trivially converges.

We have proved that if $(x_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in this metric space, then it must be convergent. Therefore this metric space is complete.

---

Are these proofs valid? In particular, is the use of contradiction sound in part 1 and does the reasoning follow in part 2? I've learned to be careful with analysis arguments, so could someone check over my work?

I am confident about part 1 but there's something about part 2 that confuses me. The completeness property only applies to Cauchy sequences, so if my results are correct then the sequence in part 1 is not Cauchy. So did I make a mistake or was $d$ carefully chosen to defy intuition?

Comment: It looks very good to me. The first sequence is not Cauchy with respect to the given distance, and it does not converge. Everything is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are all right, the metric $d$ makes your metric space being *discrete topological space*. In the latter, convergence of $(x_n)$ means that there exists $a$ such that $x_n = a$ for all $n$ big enough. You perfectly showed this using $\epsilon = \frac12<1$. As a result, the sequence $\frac1n$ does not converge.

Any Cauchy sequence thus has to have only constant terms after some $n$ because of the Cauchy condition $|x_n -x_m|<\epsilon$ for all $m,n$ big enough. As a result, you obtain a desired sequence with only constants in the tail, so it clearly converges thanks to the first argument. And surely, the sequence $\frac1n$ is not Cauchy w.r.t. the metric $d$.

Comment: Good work. It is simple and clear. +10)

Answer (score 1):

YOU are right. Indeed, this space is a discrete space, i.e., $\Bbb R$ with a discrete topology. Every sequence taking and infinite number of values in a discrete space is not convergent and every discrete space is a complete metric space.

Comment: `Every sequence in a discrete space is not convergent ` What do you mean?

Comment: @Ilya: I want to express that any infinite countable subset of discrete space has not an accumulation point. Can it be okey? Please feel free to chang me.

Comment: Constant sequences are convergent...

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thanks for your kind reminding. Something in special case I always forget. I will reedit it.

Comment: @Paul: c'mon, converging sequences are exactly those that are eventually constant, but not necessarily entirely. What you shall say that any sequence with an infinite range is not converging.

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Paul: are you considering fixing your answer? It still contains an incorrect point

Comment: @Ilya: Could you help me to edit my answer? Please fell free to edit it.